# What does does a dynamic memory request cause error?

Tags: c++, class, memory

```
class tower {
public:
    unsigned int no;             // ERROR!
    int *levels = new int[no];   // the error disappears when I comment out this line
    tower(int init) {no = init;}    
};
```

I made the class declaration show above, and for some reason, it doesn't work. The error message that shows up is: Invalid use of non-static data member 'tower::no'. Why? I'm really not sure what is going on.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not allowed to do that in the class declaration. How would the compiler know the value of `no` ? You have to defer that operation in your constructor(s).

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on the difference between declaration and definition, and what you can do in the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tower.h :

```
class Tower 
{
public:
    Tower(int size);  // Note that we're missing a destructor which 
                      // should invoke delete[] on _levels.
    unsigned int _size;
    int *_levels;  // Consider some sort of smart pointer 
                   // later when as you continue to learn C++, 
                   // or use std::vector!
};
```

In Tower.cpp :

```
Tower::Tower(int size) : _size(size), _levels(NULL)
{
    if(_size > 0)
    {
        _levels = new int[size];
    }
}
```

Check out [examples online too](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

```
class tower {
public:
    unsigned int no;
    int *levels;
    tower(int init) { no = init; levels = new int[no]; }    
};
```

**edit** In case it's not obvious, the initialization of "levels" was moved to AFTER the initialization of "no". You have to initialize "levels" after "no" because "new int[no]" won't execute properly until "no" has a value.

Comment: @JohnDibling - I think an obvious change between two snippets of code can explain itself, but sure I'll bite.

Comment: My comment and downvote were incorrect here.  I misread a key part of the original post.  In fact I composed a fairlly long answer based on that misunderstanding.  Once I realized my mistake I deleted my answer (10K+ can see it), but I cannot revert the downvote on your answer until you edit your answer, because that's how SO works.  Do that, and I will.

Comment: Oh, actually I see you already did edit.  Down vote removed and +1.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is trying to tell you that you are making invalid use of a member that is not static. That means that the value of "no" won't be concrete until some time during the constructor.

Look no further than your own constructor implementation:

```
tower(int init /*future value of no)
    // <-- this is where initialization is done by the compiler,
    // so the compiler would be trying to do
    // : m_init(new int[no]).
    // What value does "no" have right now?
{
    no = init;  // <-- you are going to assignment rather than initialization.
}
```

The correct way to do this would be with an initialization list.

```
class Tower
{
    int m_no;
    int* m_levels;
publc:
    Tower(int no_)
        : m_no(no_)
        , m_levels(no_ ? new int[no_] : nullptr)
    {
    }
};
```